# Скрипт в автозапуске не видит библиотеки. Linux

Tags: linux, автозапуск, ros

Есть скрипт на shell - soft.sh
Есть ярлык (для добавления в автозапуск) - soft.desktop, в котором прописан запуск скрипта.
soft.sh использует библиотеку ROS, и функцию из нее - rostopic

Когда я включаю систему, скрипт выполняется, но на rostopic говорит "command not found".
При том что через терминал от стандартного пользователя все исполняется на ура.
Как починить этот момент, чтобы он не ругался из автозапуска на rostopic?

source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash - в soft.sh прописывал

gksudo -gk в параметрах запуска soft.desktop тоже

От sudo из терминала не запускается (ошибка та же), только от регулярного пользователя.

Знаю, что не очень развернуто, но первый пост, прошу прощения.
ОС ubuntu 16.04

Comment: видимо, вам [сюда](http://wiki.ros.org/Support)

Comment: Мне кажется здесь проблема Linux, а не ROS. Так как ROS с точки зрения системы - пакет, к которому пользователь Root не имеет доступа. Я добавил source в файл .bashrc в каталоге Root, из под которого загружается система и не увидел результата. Может кто знает способы открыть ресурсы для всех пользователей системы?